# How can one tell if an interface is a loopback device by it's sll_ifindex?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

I have the `ifindex` number of an interface, now I want to know if that device is a loopback interface.

So far the only option seems to be retrieving its name first, then check if it start with `lo`.

Any better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the flags. There is the `IFF_LOOPBACK` flag that tells what you need.

There are several ways to get the flags, but if you know how to get the name from the `ifindex`, then retrieving the flags should be no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of the flags, which are implemented by an interface by checking the corresponding flags.

You see the constants from the [`if.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v2.6.25/include/linux/if.h) file.